# how to pass the result of one edittext to another edittext?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How do I pass the result of one edittext to another edittext? This is my example code of one edittext:

```
String a,b,c,d;  
Integer vis;  
a = txtbox1.getText().toString();  
b = txtbox2.getText().toString();
c = txtbox3.getText().toString();
d = txtbox4.getText().toString();
vis = Integer.parseInt(a)*2+Integer.parseInt(b)*3+Integer.parseInt(c)*4+Integer.parseInt(d)*5;  
tv.setText(vis.toString());
```

And I want the value of `tv.setText(vis.toString());` will be transferred to another one edittext which I will be using to be an input on my Asynctask (Server-Client communication).

Can anyone help me?

Asynctask:

```
public class ConnectToServerTask extends AsyncTask<View, Integer, Socket>
{
    private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.110";  // Kerv Server
    private static final int DEST_PORT = 1234; //port that is used

    private EditText kaboom;

    /**
     * Store provided views (used later in onPostExecute(...)).
     * 
     * Create socket to communicate with server (blocking call).
     */
    protected Socket doInBackground(View... params)
    {
        // Store provided views.
        if (params.length != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        kaboom = (EditText) params[0];


        // Create socket.
        Socket client = null;

        try
        {
            client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT); // connect to server
        } catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return client;
    }

    /**
     * Write to server.
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter printwriter;
            String messsage;

            messsage = kaboom.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
            kaboom.setText(null); // Reset the text field to blank

            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream

            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();

            client.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try with:
secondEditTextBox.setText(vis.toString());

Comment: It works but when i'm trying send that into my Java Server, it receives just a blank.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string variable and  assign the value that you need to transfer to another edittext and pass the string as argument to the function.

Comment: Can you show me an example? Consider my code above as the first edittext. :) @Mothy

Comment: string myString=vis.ToString(); and pass the myString variable which has the value of vis.ToString() to the function that you need to have the vis.ToString() value.

Comment: I Didnt get what you say. :(

Comment: pass the variable myString to the function as argument like public void AsyncTask(string myString){ secondEditText.setText(myString);}

Comment: It just work. It copies the content of one edittext to another. But when I try to send it to my Asynctask, my server just receives blank.

Comment: How are you sending it and what is the code present in AsyncTask? Please post your code

Comment: You can create a static variable like public static string myString=vis.toString(); and you can use the value anywhere within the application

Comment: Kerv, i have already posted the code...public static string myString=vis.toString();.Use the secondEditText.setText(myString); in the postExecuteMethod()

Comment: Where will i put it? On my Asynctask or the Java class that contains the vis.toString(); code?

Comment: Create the static variable in the vis.toString(); code and assign the value on the AsynTask you use secondEditText.setText(FirstClass.myString);

Comment: I'll try. I don't know if this will work. But if it does not, I will ask you again...

Answer (score 0):

If your EditText needs a result from a long calculation in AsyncTask doInBackground method then you should uptate this editexts value in onPostExcute method of asyncTask. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? We are on the same point of view. Can you please talk more on this?

Comment: You dont need to store views like that.  Just declare your asyncTask as a sub-class of your activity and update the UI in onPostExecute. Background task should not interact with the UI thread.